# Cannot set activity status to scheduled

Tags: activities

I have a site where from the Contact Summary Screen, I select Action > Phone Call (or indeed any activity)

The default status is Scheduled. WHen I save the activity I get this "You cannot record scheduled SMS activity".

Same on every activity. If I choose Completed or other status, works fine.

Have upgraded to latest CiviCRM, also latest Drupal.

Have moved servers.

Have disabled all extensions and custom fields.

Have disabled CiviCase.

Still have the problem.

Nothing in the civi error log.

Nothing in the drupal log.

Any ideas welcome.

[image]

Comment: I'd probably start by putting in some debugging in CRM/Activity/Form/Activity.php in formRule, around line 876, to see what it thinks the activity type id and pseudoconstant values are.and why that line is getting triggered.

Comment: Are you saying that it causes the call to PseudoConstant::getKey for activity type/status to somehow get mixed up with the ids for user profile fields? Can you maybe edit the question to describe how you're seeing that code come into play on your site? I'm having trouble seeing the connection and I can't reproduce it on the public demo.

Comment: Thanks Demerit. I deleted that comment as when I retested with just that change all was good. I’ll go through all changes in 5.14 and narrow it down.